# Find size/internal structure of list in Python

Tags: python

If I have a list `c` like so:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
c = [a,a]
```

What's the simplest way of finding that it's a list of length two where each element is a list of length 4? If I do `len(c)` I get `2` but it doesn't give any indication that those elements are lists or their size unless I explicitly do something like

```
print(type(c[0]))
print(len(c[0]))
print(len(c[1]))
```

I could do something like

```
import numpy as np
np.asarray(c).shape
```

which gives me `(2,4)`, but that only works when the internal lists are of equal size. If instead, the list is like

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
d = [a,b]
```

then `np.asarray(d).shape` just gives me `(2,)`. In this case, I could do something like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
1    2 non-null int64
2    1 non-null float64
3    1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

From this, I can tell that there are lists inside the original list, but I would like to be able to see this without using pandas. What's the best way to look at the internal structure of a list?

Comment: how about writing a recursive function?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis perhaps that's the best way. I was hoping there was something that already existed in Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the output format you expect, you could write a recursive function that returns nested tuples of length and shape.

### Code

```
def shape(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    shp = tuple(shape(sub) if isinstance(sub, list) else 0 for sub in lst)
    if any(x != 0 for x in shp):
        return length, shp
    else:
        return length
```

### Examples

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print(shape(lst)) # (2, (4, 4))

lst = [1, [1, 2]]
print(shape(lst)) # (2, (0, 2))

lst = [1, [1, [1]]]
print(shape(lst)) # (2, (0, (2, (0, 1))))
```

Comment: I'd also think this is the most straightforward way of doing it.

Comment: This is different from what the OP is asking. This doesn't report any sort of structure, just a rough measure of its overall size. It wouldn't differentiate, for example, between `[[1], [2], [3]]` and `[[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: I was looking for, if possible, the internal structure (something that says "2 elements, both of length 4"), not just the total number of elements.

Comment: @jss367 Is that new function more insightful regarding the shape of the list?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon In short, I think the answer is that there isn't a simple way of doing this. Your function works and is really nice but I was hoping there was a simple `structure(my_list)` type command, but alas there isn't.

Comment: @jss367 If there is one I never heard of it, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This way is returning the type of element of list, and the first item is the parent list info.

```
def check(item):
    res = [(type(item), len(item))]
    for i in item:
        res.append((type(i), (len(i) if hasattr(i, '__len__') else None)))
    return res

>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> c = [a,a]
>>> check(c)
[(list, 2), (list, 4), (list, 4)]
```